Mixed GAM with zero-inflated poisson distribution in r
I'm encountering an issue fitting a model with zero-inflated data. You can view the distribution of the response variable here:

The random effect is linked with the variable "site".
The dataframe is here:
df <- structure(list(Am06 = c(0, 0, 0, 129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66, 0), 
                     site = c("BEARavn", "LUISav", "PONTav", "TONKam", "GRANav", "VILOav", "VILOam", "PONTam", "LUCEav", "LUCEav"), 
                     smax = c(19.0284, 14.601, 22.537, 23.236273, 16.392, 21.724, 14.263, 20.507, 20.615, 19.11825), 
                     up_365 = c(0, 4.66666666666667, 2.83333333333333, 365, 11.4583333333333, 0.583333333333333, 0, 3.75, 365, 365), 
                     do_60 = c(0.208333333333333, 0, 57.1666666666667, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
                     row.names = c(234L, 1469L, 2385L, 2716L, 1075L, 2894L, 2849L, 2341L, 1347L, 1338L), 
                     class = "data.frame")

Here is my code with mgcv::gam (without random effect) and the error that follows:
mod1 <- mgcv::gam(list(as.integer(log(1+df[,1])) ~ s(smax)+ s(up_365)+ 
                  s(do_365)+ s(site, bs = "re"), ~ 1),
                  data = df, family = mgcv::ziplss())


Error in names(dat) <- object$term :    'names' attribute [1] must be
the same length as the vector [0]

gamm4V without random effect with the error too
mod2 <- gamm4V(as.integer(log(1+df[,1])) ~ s(smax) + s(up_365) + 
               s(do_365), data = df, family=ziP ,random=~(1|site))


Error in as(value, fieldClass, strict = FALSE) :    internal problem
in as(): “extended.family” is(object, "family") is TRUE, but the
metadata asserts that the 'is' relation is FALSE

Then I tried to used a list system (as for Hurdle) with a random effect, but I have another type of error that I don't understand. This is the most important model that I want to fit :
mod3 <- gam(list(as.integer(log(1+df[,1])) ~ s(smax) + s(up_365) + 
                 s(do_365) + s(site, bs = "re"),
                 ~ s(smax) + s(up_365) + s(do_365)),
            data = df, family = ziplss, method = "REML")


Error in names(dat) <- object$term :    'names' attribute [1] must be
the same length as the vector [0]

The only one (with random effect) that seems to work is this one:
mod4 <- gam(as.integer(log(1+df[,1])) ~ s(smax) + s(up_365) +
            s(do_365), data = df, random=~(1|site), family=ziP)

Can you tell me how to avoid these errors and fit at least one of these models?

Please share in your post the output of the command dput(df).

structure(list(Am06 = c(0, 0, 0, 129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 66, 0), site = c("BEARavn",
"LUISav", "PONTav", "TONKam", "GRANav", "VILOav", "VILOam", "PONTam",
"LUCEav", "LUCEav"), smax = c(19.0284, 14.601, 22.537, 23.236273,
16.392, 21.724, 14.263, 20.507, 20.615, 19.11825), up_365 = c(0,
4.66666666666667, 2.83333333333333, 365, 11.4583333333333, 0.583333333333333,
0, 3.75, 365, 365), do_60 = c(0.208333333333333, 0, 57.1666666666667,
0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(234L, 1469L, 2385L, 2716L,
1075L, 2894L, 2849L, 2341L, 1347L, 1338L), class = "data.frame")

do_365 is not available in your data frame df; instead, do_60 is present. Please update your code accordingly. Additionally, you cannot apply a spline to the character variable site. You must first transform it into a factor with df$site <- factor(df$site) before including it in the model.

You can only use families known to glmer() with gamm4 and ziP() or ziplss() aren't among those.
You must convert your character random effect variables to be factors; you can't leave them as characters otherwise you get the error you saw with gam() (the first and third errors).
random is not an argument to gam(); that your final example didn't throw an error is because ... is in the function definition for gam() and it silently ate the random argument and gam never used it (for obvious reasons).
I don't understand why you are transforming the response variable; there is no need to log transform in a Poisson model.
What you want is:
df <- transform(df, site = factor(site))
mod1 <- mgcv::gam(list(Am06 ~ s(smax) + s(up_365)+ s(do_365) +
                              s(site, bs = "re"),
                            ~ 1),
                  data = df, family = mgcv::ziplss(),
                  method = "REML")

but I doubt this is the model you want; constant zero-inflation is rarely useful, so consider modelling the binomial hurdle (the bit where you have ~ 1 in the list) using some or all of your covariates in the mean (rate) part of the model.
Note that ziplss() fits zero-inflated Poisson models as a hurdle model; a binomial hurdle for observed / not-observed and a truncated Poisson part which can only generate >0 integers. See ?ziplss.
Finally, just because you have lots of zeroes in your data doesn't mean it is zero-inflated. Zero-inflation is not something you inspect with respect to data but to a model. So, I would suggest you step back and fit a Poisson and negative binomial models to the data and then assess those models for zero-inflation. Assuming df` is transformed as per the code chunk above...
mod_p <- gam(Am06 ~ s(smax) + s(up_365)+ s(do_365) +
                    s(site, bs = "re"),
             data = df, family = poisson(), method = "REML")


mod_nb <- gam(Am06 ~ s(smax) + s(up_365)+ s(do_365) +
                     s(site, bs = "re"),
              data = df, family = nb(), method = "REML")

Then check those models for zero-inflation, perhaps via a rootogram (I have a version for GAMs in rootogram() in my gratia package), or use the DHARMa package and it's tests.
Only proceed to a zero-altered or -inflated model if those diagnostics show problems with underestimation of the zero counts.
